# wcf Service could not be activated

Tags: iis-7, wcf

It's a .svc IIS hosted service with ssl and membership.

My wcf client reports:

```
System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException was unhandled
  Message="The requested service, 'https://www.greenjump.nl/WebServices/OrderService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information."
  Source="mscorlib"
```

On the server I get:
System.ArgumentException
          This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.
          Parameter name: item

The strange thing is this only happens on the production server, the same code and config
on the localhost development server works fine.
I only change the endpoint address and  
from computer name to www.webdomain.com

more server trace

```
<ExceptionType>
  System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
</ExceptionType>
<Message>
  This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.
  Parameter name: item
</Message>
<StackTrace>
  at System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection.InsertItem(Int32 index, Uri item)
  at System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedCollection`1.Add(T item)
  at System.ServiceModel.UriSchemeKeyedCollection..ctor(Uri[] addresses)
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
  at SharpShop.Web.StructureMap.StructureMapServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
  at SharpShop.Web.StructureMap.StructureMapServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
  at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
  at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
  at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
  at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
  at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)
  at System.ServiceModel.PartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke()
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ProcessCallbacks()
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.CompletionCallback(Object state)
  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
  at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
  at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
```

config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttps">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="128000"/>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" >
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="https://www.greenjump.nl"/>
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WsHttpWithAuthBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"
                                roleProviderName="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
              membershipProviderName="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WsHttpWithAuthBehavior" name="SharpShop.Services.OrderService">
        <endpoint address="https://www.greenjump.nl/WebServices/OrderService.svc" 
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="wsHttps"
                  contract="SharpShop.Services.IOrderService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="www.greenjump.nl" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902643/cant-activate-wcf-service/36487750#36487750

Comment: Shared the steps on below url:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902643/cant-activate-wcf-service/36487750#36487750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by IIS handling of multiple host headers.
Like blowdart said here.
error: This collection already contains an address with scheme http.

and somewhat more elaborate here 
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/12883/274592.aspx

using the first baseAddresses[0] is not an option for me because my baseAddresses were 
http://localhost/WebServices/OrderService.svc
http://www.greenjump.nl/WebServices/OrderService.svc
https://vps2051.xlshosting.net/WebServices/OrderService.svc
in this order of course I could do [1] but I don't like this configuration dependency.

It seems my problem is somewhat more complex due to the https binding, this is the ServiceHostFactory I came up with:

```
 public class MyServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {

        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            Uri webServiceAddress = baseAddresses[0]; //default to first

            if (HttpContext.Current != null) //this only works when aspNetCompatibilityEnabled=true
            {
                string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
                var goodAddress = baseAddresses.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Host == host);//try to find address with same hostname as request
                if(goodAddress!=null)
                {
                    webServiceAddress = goodAddress;
                }
                Type[] sslServices = { typeof(OrderService)  };//add all https services here
                if (sslServices.Any(s => s == serviceType))
                {
                    UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(webServiceAddress);
                    builder.Scheme = "https";
                    builder.Port = 443; //fails if you use another port
                    webServiceAddress = builder.Uri;
                }
            }
            return new ServiceHost(serviceType, webServiceAddress);
        }
    }
```

Still this feels hacky, and should be solved by microsoft.

Comment: @Medo Did you try adding the port to the endpoint and the base prefix? That was one solution so that you wouldn't need to do this custom factory.

Answer (score 8):

If you're hosting in IIS you don't need the base address section - as it's IIS's site configuration that provides it - so remove that section.

There is a "problem" when IIS is configured for multiple host headers though, in which case you need to use a custom factory which removes all the addresses aside from the one you want. A simple example is

```
namespace Example
{
    public class GenericServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, 
                                                         Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            //return the first...
            return new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would use that in your .svc file

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Service="MyImplementationClass"
    Factory="Example.GenericServiceHostFactory"
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two guesses: you've got multiple <endpoint address="" entries in there somewhere.

They might not have the same values but they might resolve to the same name.

Or since it looks like you're using https://, do you use http on the dev machine and https on the live one?

If so, do you have separate endpoint addresses for both?  In theory you shouldn't do this - you'd enable transport security on an http base address, which will prevent it from being able to be called on anything other than https.

Technically http and https are both http schemes.

Comment: only one endpoint, and on de dev machine I also use https
did a search solution just to be sure, no other endpoints found.
It works in devserver I only replace domain name and endpoint location on production

Comment: looking at the config - have you tried removing the explicit 'address=' from your main service's endpoint?  You don't need to specify a base address if the service will 'begin' at the .svc file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a prefix to your production server in ther web config:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    <add prefix="https://www.greenjump.nl:443" />
  </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

This would be added to `<system.serviceModel>`

And your endpoint should look like this:

```
   <endpoint address="https://www.greenjump.nl:443/WebServices/OrderService.svc" 
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttps"
              contract="SharpShop.Services.IOrderService">
```

Otherwise you can always overload the ServiceFactory like one of the other commentators suggested

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by following below steps using Visual Studio 2013:

1. Go to your project folder where you have your *.svc file
2. Right Click *.svc file --> View in browser
3. Validate if you are able to browse the service
4. Go to your project folder where you have your app.config file or where you want to consume the service.
5. Right click project-->Add-->Service Reference
6. Click Discover-->Under Services Select Service-->Give desired name to your service reference-->Click OK
7. It will create "ServiceReference1" under the folder "Service References" & automatically create/update app.config file
   [image]