# Service, Endpoint not found

Tags: wcf, service

I have a working service done in WCF.  It works fine in my other machine.  Now, I tried to run the same (I just copy and paste) it to the other machine.  But, when I run my service I got an error "Endpoint not found"

What seems to be the problem?

I have the following codes in my config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" connectionString="data source=localhost;initial catalog=PracticeTests;integrated security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <services>
      <service name="BuyPracticeTestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BuyPracticeTestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">

        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>

        <behavior name="web">

          <webHttp/>

        </behavior>

      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />


  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
       <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
       <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>

  <runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">

      <dependentAssembly>

        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />

        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />

      </dependentAssembly>

      <dependentAssembly>

        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />

        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />

      </dependentAssembly>

    </assemblyBinding>

  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Sample Iservice

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       UriTemplate = "getQuestionOptionList/{qid}")]
    List<QuestionOptions> GetQuestionOptionList(string qid);
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: when you moved your service to a new machine did you also move your database?  You have the config string pointing at the same machine the service is running on.

Comment: also look here for troubleshooting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902643/cant-activate-wcf-service/10902740#10902740